# window.load only works on refresh

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have this jquery code:

```
$(window).load ->
  $("#introduction h2").slabText viewportBreakpoint: 0
```

But it only executes the code when I refresh the page. So when I click on a link and then back to my homepage the text doesn't get rendered by `slabText`.

I'm putting the code in `$(window).load ->` because if I put it in `$(document).ready ->` the code gets fired before the fonts are loaded by my css which causes it to fail.

Comment: What language is this ... it doesn't look like JavaScript?

Comment: It's CoffeeScript, @Kolban. It's pretty neat, you should check it out: coffeescript.org

Comment: It's coffeescript. It's the SASS for jQuery. Why is my question getting downvoted? Was it really for the Javascript tag? :?

Comment: @Kolban CoffeeScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the fonts either in you html head section or dynamically (and synchronously) inside document.ready right before your code, because that's where initialization code belongs.

Comment: So it's expected behaviour of `(window).load` to only work when the page is being loaded for the first time?

Comment: It's related to cache: http://www.seangofus.com/journal/entry/fixing-jquery-window-load-webkit-issue

I thought they'd have this fixed by now but it seems (from your own experience) they haven't.

Comment: Hm, looks like something strange is going on. I've added `$('h2').click ->
    console.log 'hi'` to my `$(document).ready ->`. When I refresh the page the clicks log a 'hi' when I revisit the page the click function doesn't add a 'hi' to the log.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code. Problem is that my rails Turbolinks was caching the page causing the page to not reload. Using this code fixed the problem.

```
ready = ->

  $("#introduction h2").slabText viewportBreakpoint: 0

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

Eventually I ended up removing turbolinks all together since I'm working on a single page app.